# UWP: ILT0032: Failed to compile serialization code

Tags: c#, uwp, native, .net-native

When I compile my UWP app in Release mode, I get the following errors:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added. at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key,
>   TValue value, Boolean add) at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderCodeGen.WriteLiteralStructMethod(StructMapping
>   structMapping) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderCodeGen.WriteStructMethod(StructMapping
>   structMapping) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderCodeGen.GenerateMethod(TypeMapping
>   mapping) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationCodeGen.GenerateReferencedMethods()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderCodeGen.GenerateEnd(String[]
>   methods, XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Hashtable assemblies,
>   String outputDir, String assemblyNameBase, IEnumerable`1
>   referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[]
>   types, XmlMapping[] mappings, CompilerParameters parameters, String
>   outputDir, String assemblyNameBase, IEnumerable`1
>   referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[]
>   types, String outputDir, String assemblyNameBase, IEnumerable`1
>   referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, List`1 wcfSerializers,
>   Boolean loadAssembly) at
>   SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args) ILT0032:
>   Failed to compile serialization code. See the build log for error
>   details.

I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20d3040a-c85c-4549-85a5-972d8686cc7a/uwpcant-compile-uwp-app-with-net-native-in-release-mode?forum=wpdevelop) describing the same problem. But the proposed solution to remove KnownType Attributes of primitive types, did not apply to my problem.

The error disappears, when I uncheck "Compile with .NET Native tool chain", but then the binary analyzer fails with the following errors:

> dotnet-Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator.dll has failed the
>   AppContainerCheck check.

The generated XmlSerialization assemblies don't work (no faster serialization) for me and I would turn the generation of these assemlies off, if I know how.

Does anyone know how to fix this Release compile problem with UWP?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/serialization-and-metadata), it specifically talks about XML serialization and how to solve its problems.